# Unit testing crash at cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, unit-testing

I have a simple tableview with some rows. Each row is a custom cell with an xib file. I have implemented the delegate and datasource and its working fine when I run the app. This is the way I have implemented it.

```
class P: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        registerCell()
    }

    func registerCell() {
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    #number of rows implemented here

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = "Great"
        return cell
    }
}
```

This code works fine.

The problem is when I try to unit test the tableView I am facing problem. This is how I am unit testing

```
class MockPController: PController {

}

class PControllerTests: XCTestCase {
    let mpc = MockPController()

    //THIS IS WORKING
    func testNumberOfSections() {
        mpc.viewDidLoad()
        XCTAssertEqual(mpc.numberOfSections(in: mpc.tableView), 5)
    }

    func testTitleForPCells() {
        mpc.viewDidLoad()
        var cell = mpc.tableView(mpc.tableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)) as! PCell
        //THE APP CRASHES AT THE CELLFORROWATINDEXPATH FUNCTION IN ACTUAL CODE - HERE "let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PCell"
        //APP CRASHES HERE SAYING "Could not cast value of type 'Project.PCell' to 'ProjectTests.PCell'
    }
}
```

On getting this app crash I added a override function for registerCell() in MockPController, so the new MockPController becomes

```
class MockPController: PController {
    override func registerCell() {
        self.tableView.register(PCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
}
```

After adding this override function I am not getting crash at the dequeueReusableCell, but now app crashes saying that the outlet variable titleLabel is nil.

So I guess it is not getting the right instance of the cell because of the override registerCell() function. But without it also app crashes.

What am I doing wrong?

I searched google but I am not getting any result.

Comment: All *outlets* are automatically filled when your `UIViewController` is loaded from the storyboard. When you instantiate the view controller explicitly, as you are doing in your test code, you lose all that set up. This might be causing your current issue. (You could try creating it from the `UIStoryboard` object instead but then you won’t be able to use a mocked VC subclass.)

Comment: @PauloMattos can you post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You seem trying to test `UITableView`'s `cellForRowAt:` method. Which is not what you want. You want to test your `PCell` class.
To do so, instanciate a `PCell` with superclass init `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)`. Then call a method of your own like `pcell.doSomethingThatSetTheTitle()` and assert that the title of your cell is what you expect.

EDIT:

```
func testTitleForPCells() {
    let cell = PCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "anything")
    let model = Model(title: "FOO")
    cell.setMyModel(model)
    XCTAssertEqual(cell.titleLabel.text, model.title)
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer, possible some sample code.

Comment: But your code is setting model separately in the unit test function itself. So basically it won't run cellforrow function which totally defeat the purpose of unit testing.

Comment: Then what do you want to test ? Delegate or cell ? And what does your `cellForRowAt:` looks like ?

Comment: I want to test the cell. I have already added my cellforrow function in the question.

Comment: Sorry didn’t see your implementation. So, if you want to test cell, why are you calling the delegate’s method ? The documentation for this says : « If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its init(style:reuseIdentifier:) method. For nib-based cells, this method loads the cell object from the provided nib file. If an existing cell was available for reuse, this method calls the cell’s prepareForReuse() method instead.« In your test initialize a cell directly, without using the delegate